# How to store structured data from Numba prange

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a function like this:

```
@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, parallel=True)
def parallelLoop():

    X = [None] * 10

    for i in prange(10):
        X[i] = foo()
```

where `foo()` returns a variable size numpy structured array. Running this gives me the error:

```
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
invalid setitem with value of (list(float64), float64, float64, float64, int64, array(float64, 2d, C)) to element of none
```

How can I store the results of parallel threads in Numba, where the results are structured arrays of different sizes?